# Show div once clicked a link and hide when again clicked the same link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <span>Show categories</span>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

If I click the above **"Show Categories"**,it should display the content class div and at the same time the **Show Categories** word should be change to **Hide Categories**.When I again click the **Hide Categories** ,it should hide the div and again the word should change to **Show Category**.

How can I achieve it simply without using  Bootstrap collapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
var flag = true;
$('#dd').click(function() {
  //This
  $('.content').toggle();
  $('#dd').html(flag == false ? "Hide categories" : 'Show categories')
  flag = !flag;
  //OR this
  $(".content").css("display", flag ? "block" : "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <span id="dd">Hide categories</span>
</div>
<div class="content"><h2>Some title here</h2>Something happening here!</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved by using jquery `toggle()` method.

```js
$('#cate').click(function(){
    $('.content').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <span id="cate">Show categories</span>
</div>
<div class="content">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery:

```js
var s = document.getElementById('switchme');
var c = document.getElementById('content');
c.style.display = 'none';

s.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  [c.style.display, e.target.textContent] = (c.style.display === 'none') // check visibility
    ? ['block', 'Hide categories'] 
    : ['none', 'Show categories'];
})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <span id="switchme">Show categories</span>
</div>
<div class="content" id="content">Content</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer